# Xunit with Moq, Can not instantiate proxy of class: EFCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry[Main.Domain.Contact]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, moq, xunit

I get the following error on the commented line of my unit test,

> System.ArgumentException: 'Can not instantiate proxy of class:
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1[[Main.Domain.Contact,
> PublicKeyToken=null]]. Could not find a parameterless constructor.
> (Parameter 'constructorArguments')'

indicates that it is my rich domain class? but it has two public constructors with no parameters and with parameters and there's an update method in the model, looks like this:

Constructors:

```
        public Contact(
        Guid franchiseId,
        string firstName,
        string? middleName,
        string lastName,
        bool doNotContact,
        string? emailAddress,
        IEnumerable<ContactGroupContact>? contactGroupContacts = null,
        ICollection<ContactNote> contactNotes = null
            )
```

And the other constructor;

```
        public Contact()
       {
        ContactGroupContacts = new HashSet<ContactGroupContact>();
        ContactTags = new HashSet<ContactTag>();
        Messages = new HashSet<Message>();
       }
```

Update method;

```
    public override void Update(Contact entity)
    {
        Initialize(this);

        this.FirstName = entity.FirstName;
        this.LastName = entity.LastName;
        this.CalledName = entity.CalledName;
        this.DoNotContact = entity.DoNotContact;
        this.EmailAddress = entity.EmailAddress;
        this.MiddleName = entity.MiddleName;
        this.MobileNumber = entity.MobileNumber;
        ...
```

it has ICollection of ContactNotes and ICollection of ContactGroup tho. (I guess they are called shadow properties, cascade delete?)

I have tried several solutions that I could find on the internet, mock some objects and methods yet nothing has solved my problem so far. My unit test;

```
[Fact]
public void Update_ShouldCallModifyUpdatedEntity()
{
    //Arrange
    Contact contact = A.Fake<Contact>();
    contact.UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
    contact.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.MinValue;

    Contact contactTbu = A.Fake<Contact>();
    contactTbu.UniqueId = contact.UniqueId;
    contactTbu.Address1 = "Test Address";
    #region Utils
    var internalEntityEntry = new InternalEntityEntry(
        new Mock<IStateManager>().Object,
        new RuntimeEntityType("T", typeof(Contact), false, null, null, null, ChangeTrackingStrategy.Snapshot, null, false),
        contact);
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTests");
    #endregion

    var _dbContext = new Mock<DbContext>(optionsBuilder.Options);
    var _dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Contact>>();


    _dbContext.Setup(x => x.Set<Contact>().AsQueryable()).Returns(_dbSet.Object);
    _dbContext.Setup(x => x.Set<Contact>()).Returns(_dbSet.Object);
    _dbContext.Setup(x => x.Set<Contact>().Find(contact.UniqueId)).Returns(contact);
    _dbContext.Setup(x => x.Entry(It.IsAny<Contact>())).Returns(new EntityEntry<Contact>(internalEntityEntry));
    _dbContext.Setup(x => x.Entry(contact).CurrentValues.SetValues(contactTbu));//here
    _dbSet.Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<Contact>()))
        .Returns(contact);

    //Act

    _sut = new Repository<Contact>(_dbContext.Object);
    _sut.Update(contact);


    //Assert
    _dbContext.Verify(x=>x.Entry(contact));
    _dbContext.Verify(x => x.Entry(It.IsAny<Contact>()).CurrentValues.SetValues(contact));
}
```

Comment: I'd highly discourage mocking the `DbContext` and `DbSet` - doing so **correctly** is pretty hard. You'd better use this approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#sqlite-in-memory

Comment: is this approach still applicable if the project is DbFirst?

Comment: I'd say yes because I don't see which difference it should make between DB first or last - `DbContext` and POCOs are created in both scenarios